# Help explaining CGI::Header error, involving BIND from CGI.pm

Tags: perl, cgi

I've tried searching but I can't find the following error found in my error_log:

```
[Fri Jun 24 16:39:34 2011] [error] [client ::1] CGI::header: Can't upgrade BIND (1) to 9 at /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/adjsearch.cgi line 428
```

Refers to the CGI.pm command: `LINE 428 print header();
 Line 429 print start_html();`

Can someone please tell me what it means? Even just what BIND is?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you show us line 428 (with some context) of the adjsearch.cgi file?

Comment: Sorry, I've added it.  Any more context is needed?

Comment: Yeah, it would be helpful to see the exact line of code, along with 5-10 lines before and after.

Comment: You think you could choose a more descriptive title? :-) Thanks!

Comment: @Randy Marsh: Thanks for letting me know, hopefully the title is better.

@Flimsy: Not sure what code related to the `print header()` would help. It's surrounded by unrelated things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BIND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIND) is system software for domain name lookups.

A handful of BIND error messages in your webserver logs is indicative of a network glitch, not necessarily anything wrong with the code for your website.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Mysteriously, the error is gone and all is working fine!

Comment: Actuall this isn't true (well, it's true that BIND is a widely used piece of DNS software), but this error message is from perl itself. I've just hit it in some really curly embedded perl/xs stuff and it seems to be an oddly blessed reference - maybe perl thinks is bound to a builtin via tie?

Answer (score 0):

Following on from my comment above, I hit this message, and how I fixed it might be instructive although I'm still not exactly sure what it means. The code I was working on was some fairly tricky XS code (ie. implementing perl functions in C) and I wasn't properly restoring the stack pointer.

Of course with stack pointer bugs, the bug often shows up later - in this case in some perl code that was using @_ (which under certain circumstances is a simple gateway to the stack).

So basically, this message appears to be triggered by a corrupt stack pointer, but exactly what it means I don't know. grepping the perl source may prove instructive.